# Can I remake other people's websites using HTML/CSS (only for education purposes) and post in Code Review?

Tags: discussion, legal

As I begin to learn Web Development I want to practice as much as possible and I thought that choosing random websites and trying to code them would be a good way to practice and improve my coding skills. My question is: can I do that and post the code here in Code Review to ask for help?

Comment: If you are only writing HTML & CSS, I don't see much of a point in getting your "code" (markup) reviewed. Web design is subjective. Furthermore, the source for any webpage can be easily viewed, so you could very easily just study the actual structure and style of any page that interests you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to look at [Do I have to worry about copyright issues for code posted on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow). The websites you're copying are generally going to have copyright notices. They may conflict with the stackexchange.com copyright.

Comment: Copyright usually applies to content (ie the articles) not the structure of a site. If you are just using the structure (layout) then fair-use usually includes using for educational purposes. IMNAL